# Will my Navigo Pass be replenishable next year?

Tags: tickets, france, paris, sncf, ratp

NYC OMNI "tap & go" passes are refillable and do not expire for 5 years.

The French equivalent is Navigo: **I purchased a weekly pass** for 5 + 30 Euros.  Can I reuse the pass next year in Paris?  2 years from now?

Answer (score 7):

A Navigo pass (the phyiscal card) is [valid for 10 years](https://www.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/aide-et-contacts/generalites-supports-validations/quelle-est-la-duree-de-vie-dun-support-sans-contact). This applies to all the types: Navigo Easy (transferable, can be loaded with single-trip tickets and day passes), Navigo Découverte (personal, for non-residents, can be loaded with day/week/month passes, that's the one you have), and Navigo (personal, for residents, can be loaded with day/week/month/year passes).

Comment: What does "nominative" mean?

Comment: @AR-solidarityforModstrike: I *think* it means that it has to be used by a particular person (i.e., "non-transferrable"), but hopefully Gilles will return to answer the question definitively.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Indeed, my bad, in this context English doesn't use the same Latin/French-derived word.

Comment: side note: nothing prevents residents from using Navigo Découverte

Comment: (+1) In fact, if it stops working, you can just get a new one from any RATP desk.

Comment: I’m amazed that they actually say they will automatically exchange passes after 10 years. Of course this is only possible le if the pass is registered (so they have your address), which is not the case for all types.

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely keep the card and reuse it much later. I’m not sure if there’s any guarantee of how long the card will be usable, but unless there’s an incompatible technology change there’s no reason you can’t use it.

As far as I know passes are not actively invalidated after a set time.

So you should be able to reuse the card in a year or two (and probably much longer) just by loading a new pass onto it.

Sadly the Navigo system is a sorry mess and there are different types of cards which support different types of passes and tickets and so on (and many tickets just can’t be loaded on a card at all), but weekly passes and a few others will clearly be loadable.

You can check what you can load onto the card by using either of the apps which support it (like the one from RATP, the company which operates the metro and some parts of the RER, tram and bus networks): go into the tickets tab, read the card, and it will let you know what you can load onto it.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is asking if, next year, he can replenish their Navigo _card_ with a new Navigo _weekly pass_.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Yes, that’s indeed what I think he asks and what I’m writing he should be able to. A weekly pass for sure, other types of passes and tickets, depends on the card type.

Comment: The physical passes have an expiry date, which is 10 years for all types as far as I can find.

Comment: (+1) In fact, if it stops working, you can just get a new one from any RATP desk.